# How do I open an alert window if the new value is duplicated in the existing value in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here, there is a global variable. (An array type)

```
var obj = [];
```

Gets the value entered in input.

```
var d_idx = $('#d_idx').val();
   var d_firstDate = $('#firstDate').val();
   var d_secondDate = $('#secondDate').val();
   var chozyintime = $('#ri_chozyinTime').val();
   var zaezyintime = $('#ri_zaezyinTime').val();
```

"chozyintime" and "zaezyintime" are declared as arrays.

Because you can input multiple values.

```
  var chozyinArray = [chozyintime];
  var zaezyinArray = [zaezyintime];
```

At this time, I gave the condition. I will explain it later.

first,

```
if(obj.length <= 0)
{
   firstAddData(d_idx, d_firstDate, d_secondDate, chozyinArray, zaezyinArray);
}
```

If the size of the initial obj is zero, push the input value to obj.

firstAaddData function is :

```
   function firstAddData(d_idx, d_firstDate, d_secondDate, chozyinArray, zaezyinArray)
    {
       obj.push
       (
          {
             "d_idx" : d_idx,
             "ri_firstDate" : d_firstDate,
             "ri_secondDate" : d_secondDate,
             "ri_chozyinTime" : chozyinArray,
             "ri_zaezyinTime" : zaezyinArray
          }
       );
    }
```

Second obj.length> = 1,

At this time, the conditions described above are set.

This is, Of the values   of the first pushed obj,

d_firstDate, and d_secondDate are compared with the newly inputted d_firstDate and d_secondDate.

```
        else if(obj.length >= 1)
      {
         var filterObj = obj.filter(function(cur)
         {
              return cur.ri_firstDate == d_firstDate && cur.ri_secondDate == d_secondDate;
           })

           if(filterObj.length > 0)
           {
              filterObj.forEach(function(cur, idx)
              {
                 if(chozyintime != "" && chozyintime != null)
                 {
                  cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime);
                 }
              })
           }
           else
           {
              firstAddData(d_idx, d_firstDate, d_secondDate, chozyinArray, zaezyinArray);
           }
      }
```

As a result, I got the following output.

```
{ri_zaezyinTime=[1231,1421,2561], ri_firstDate=2017-12-15, ri_chozyinTime=[5212, 2314], ri_secondDate=2017-12-26, d_idx=1}
```

However, exception handling is not implemented for duplicate values.

When you add a new input value (chozyintime), Compared to the n elements in the array, I want to make the alert window pop up when there are duplicate values.

How should I write code to implement what I want to implement?

I need your feedback. Help.